# dovecot create Virtual folders (imap search)

Tags: dovecot

I have taken a look at [virtual folders](https://doc.dovecot.org/configuration_manual/virtual_plugin/) and have it working. The couple of the folders I have set up are All Mail and Flagged by creating the respective `dovecot-virtual` file.

The `dovecot-virtual` files seems to be needed in each users mailbox.

How can I auto create the required `dovecot-virtual` files for every mailbox?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a pretty old question, but if you are still wondering, if i understood correctly what you were trying to achieve, you have to write `auto = subscribe` in each virtual mailbox in *15-mailboxes.conf*, like so:

```
namespace inbox {
  mailbox "Flagged messages" {
    special_use = \Flagged
    auto = subscribe
    comment = Flagged messages
  }
}
```